# How to preserve JWT token across Angular components

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF backend running JWT for authorization, I've got a UserService on my angular front end that handles getting the token, validation, and refreshing.  My question is how to effectively preserve the token across other components?

In my app component I want to call the API using the JWT token but don't know how to preserve the token generated from the login component.

```
public login(user) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/', JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.updateData(data['token']);
          console.warn(data['token']);
      },
      err => {
        this.errors = err['error'];
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: the simplest way would be to save it in a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) object of the browser. I'd go with the second approach as localStorage is more trendy nowadays.

Comment: @Unsikable is right! Also look into HttpInterceptor to attach the JWT token on calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may:

1. Create a `token` property on your service
2. Store the obtained token on this property
3. Create a `getToken()` method to retrieve it from outside

Code:

```
token = '';

public login(user) {
  this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/', JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.updateData(data['token']);
        console.warn(data['token']);
        this.token = data['token'];
    },
    err => {
      this.errors = err['error'];
    }
  );
}

getToken() {
  return this.token;
}
```

Then you may inject `UserService` on the component on which you want to use the token and call `getToken()` to retrieve it.

Also, if you're doing several requests across your application that requires this token, a better idea is to use an [http interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) to include it on the requests (you may use the same approach mentioned above, calling `getToken()` inside the interceptor).